# Exchange 2010 Edge multisite

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

Can one edge server running exchange 2010 Service Pack 3 be subscribed to multiple AD sites?
Or it can only be subscribed to a single site?

Answer (score 1):

No.

[A site may have multiple Edge Transport servers subscribed to it, but an Edge Transport server can only be subscribed to a single Active Directory site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997438%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

> One or more Edge Transport servers can be subscribed to a single Active Directory site. However, an Edge Transport server can't be subscribed to more than one Active Directory site. If you have more than one Edge Transport server deployed, each server can be subscribed to a different Active Directory site. Each Edge Transport server requires an individual Edge Subscription.